# System call: once and multiple, which is better?

Tags: c++, system-calls

I have a kernel driver to serve I2C stuff.

It supports single R/W or batching (multiple) R/W via I2C

In case batching, what is the good way to go:

1. Transfer batch data from user to kernel. Then call I2C multiple times from kernel
2. Call single R/W multiple times from user.

Which way is better ?

Comment: what has this got to do with c++?

Comment: user application I am implementing is c++

Comment: Have you measured it?

Comment: No, at the moment I am using way #1, but it'll get an issue with another OS. Because, I transferred a batch data, and it's not in sequence. So for Linux we can call copy_from_user whenever we want. But for another OS, it allows to transfer data to kernel only once. It meant I have to do pack and unpack. The code look urgly and waste effort.

Comment: System calls are orders of magnitude more expensive than mere function calls. Minimize them.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are taking about a trivial exokernel a syscall will involve a context switch in hardware. This will take magnitudes more time than a function call or copying even a page of data around a few times.

I'm assuming you aren't talking about megabytes of data but just a few bytes. Better to pack and unpack them and absolutely reduce the number of system calls.

Comment: It can also cause suspension and rescheduling of the calling thread, and it also requires copying of parametrs from user soace to kernel soace, and copying of results and errors in the other direction, both of which are expensive.